# why my program not printing empid with the following credentials?

Tags: c

I have written a employee database using structure i am giving these following credentials

employee name sachin mirajkar
employee id abcde12345
employee salary as 123456789

for this input only the emplpyee id is not showing on the screen please help

```
#include <stdio.h>
struct employees_database {
char name[30],salary[12],empid[11];
};
int main()
{
struct employees_database emp[1];
int i,j;
for(i=0;i<1;i++)
{
    printf("Enter name of employee: ");
    scanf("%[^\n]s",emp[i].name);
    for(j=0;emp[i].name[j];j++)
    {
        if(!((emp[i].name[j]>'@' && emp[i].name[j]<'[')||(emp[i].name[j]>'`' && emp[i].name[j]<'{')||(emp[i].name[j]==' ')))
            goto END;
    }
    printf("\n Enter employee id:");
    scanf("%s",emp[i].empid);
    for(j=0;emp[i].empid[j];j++)
    {
        if(!((emp[i].empid[j]>'@' && emp[i].empid[j]<'[')||(emp[i].empid[j]>'`' && emp[i].empid[j]<'{')||(emp[i].empid[j]>'/' && emp[i].empid[j]<':')))
            goto END;
    }
    printf("\n Enter salary:");
    scanf("%s",emp[i].salary);
    for(j=0;emp[i].salary[j];j++)
    {
        if(!(emp[i].salary[j]>'/' && emp[i].salary[j]<':'))
           goto END;
    }
}
printf("\nEmployee ID \t  Employee name  \t\t Employee salary\n");
for(i=0;i<1;i++)
    printf(" %s \t %s \t\t %s \n",emp[i].empid,emp[i].name,emp[i].salary);
return 0;
if(0)
    END: printf("enter valid credentials\n");
}
```

Comment: `scanf("%[^\n]s",emp[i].name);` - does that look correct?

Answer (score 1):

please check your scanf() function calls.

changing

```
scanf("%[^\n]s",emp[i].name);
```

to

```
scanf("%s",emp[i].name);
```

should do the trick

Comment: `scanf("%s"` is harmful. Please don't advise it. Use `scanf("%29s", emp[i].name);`

Comment: @KamilCuk I tried for `scanf("%29s",emp[i].name);` it didn't worked

Comment: @ElfoDerElf  if I used `scanf("%s",emp[i].name);` then it will delimit the string to a space i.e whatever I enter after a space it won't be stored

Comment: @sachin `scanf` delimeters all input with whitespaces (tab, space, newline). If you want to read a string with spaces in it, don't use `scanf` - use `getchar()` in a loop. (or `getline` with delimeter if you have it).

Comment: @sachinmirajkar did you already try to use fgets() in a do-while loop?